# How do I use the cylindrical shell method to find this volume?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Can anyone help me out? Cant seem to get the answer..

Comment: What have you tried? Please add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _5^94\pi (y-2)\sqrt{9-y}dy=\frac{1472 \pi }{15}$$

using the cylindrical shell  method

Comment: May I ask why is it (y-2)^2 and not just y-2?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $9-x^2=5$ when $x=\pm2$, it is reasonable to assume that the region we are looking for is between $x=-2$ and $x=2$. The volume of the region inside $y=f(x)$ is
$$
\int_{-2}^2\pi(f(x)-2)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: You need to subtract $36\pi $

Comment: We need to compute the volume inside $f(x)=9-x^2$ and subtract the volume inside $f(x)=5$. Use the integral above to compute both of these volumes.